# how to automatically logout when the user closes the tab in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-8

I am writing a code in laravel but when the user leaves the page it is not automatically signing out

when i tried to figure out it started to logout when any of the button/sidebar clickables are clicked on the page ,give me a solution

Answer (score -2):

create the folder like this public/js/logout.js or resources/js/logout.js

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/logout', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', '{{ csrf_token() }}');
    xhr.send();
});
```

include that file in html template in  tag or if you are using any layout file than you can also add in that

```
<script src="{{ asset('path/to/logout.js') }}"></script>
```

define route to handle the logout request

```
Route::post('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
```

to work with csrf_token inline the csrf token

```
 window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() 
{ var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open('POST', '/logout', true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', 'your-csrf-token'); 
xhr.send(); });
```

Note that : your Auth\LoginController class, make sure that you have the logout
If it is not present that you can add it or use the default AuthenticatesUsers trait provided by Laravel

Comment: `logout.js` won't be parsed by Blade

Comment: create the folder like this public/js/logout.js or resources/js/logout.js

Comment: Still won't be parsed by Blade, how do you expect `{{ csrf_token() }}` to work in a `.js` file?

Comment: inline the csrf  token window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/logout', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', 'your-csrf-token');
    xhr.send();
});

Comment: @brombeer thanks for the suggestion I have done it